# How to change value from a string function inside of Text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the value of `Text Widget` in `Flutter`. I have tried to use `Stateful Widget` and `setState()` method, it works well when I initialized the `String` and update the value like this:

```
String textHolder = "example text" ;

void changeText(){
    setState(() {
      textHolder = 'Resend OTP';
    });
  }

Row buildTimer() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TweenAnimationBuilder(
          tween: Tween(begin: 120, end: 0.0),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 120),
          builder: (_, dynamic value, child) => 
         
          Text(
            textHolder, //call the string
            style: const TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                fontSize: fontSmallerSize,
                height: 0.8,
                color: ColorConstants.basicColor,
              ),
          ),
          onEnd: changeText, //update the value
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

In my case I can't use that kind of `String`, because I have to pass a value inside of the `String`. Due to that reason, I tried to use `String function` instead and initialized it like this:

```
String textHold (double value){
   textHolder = "Resend OTP in " + _minutes(value) + ":" + _seconds(value);
   return textHolder;
}
```

Because of that, the value of `Text Widget` doesn't change. How to change the value of `Text Widget` properly based on my case?. I'm new to `Flutter` stuffs, any kind of helps would be appreciated.

```
class _UpdateTextTimerState extends State<UpdateTextTimer> {

  String textHolder = " " ;

  String textHold (double value){
    textHolder = "Resend OTP in " + _minutes(value) + ":" + _seconds(value);
    return textHolder;
  }

  void changeText(){
    setState(() {
      textHolder = 'Resend OTP';
      //print(textHold(0).substring(0,11));
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 24,
          child: buildTimer(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

   Row buildTimer() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TweenAnimationBuilder(
          tween: Tween(begin: 120, end: 0.0),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 120),
          builder: (_, dynamic value, child) => 
         
          Text(
            textHold(value), //this is how do I call my text 
            style: const TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                fontSize: fontSmallerSize,
                height: 0.8,
                color: ColorConstants.basicColor,
              ),
          ),
          onEnd: changeText, //this is how do I change the String when the timer is ended up
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  String _minutes(double value){
    String mMinute = ((value/60)%60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return mMinute;
  }

  String _seconds(double value){
    String mSeconds = (value % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return mSeconds;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using tweenanimation I will suggest to use Timer in that case. That timer will update your text based on setState 
@Proxima

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html

This will help you out. Here you just need to handle setting up and re-setting those timer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @AnkitTale, gonna try this out

Comment: anyway is it impossible using my approach?

Comment: Here is some help I found 
https://fluttercorner.com/flutter-countdown-timer/

Comment: It's very much tricky to keep updating text in TweenAnimation. As I know color change can be done on condition but not over it.